GT table with R - Is it possible to use tab_spanner or something similar for an Interactive table
I am using GT table a lot, and want to make these tables interactive. But when using tab_spanner for two or more columns and setting opt_interactive(active = TRUE), the spanner is gone. Does anyone know how to fix it.
I am using opt_interactive() both before and after several formatting options, the result is the same, it does not work for me. Normally I want spanners for 2 to 4 columns on every table.

You should provide a reproducible example with some code and a dataset (mtcars for instance) for others to test your issue easily.

It is possible in gt 0.11.0
